# Changing repository description in git

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'd like to change repository description of the project I'm working on but "Edit" button does not appear in GitHub web site.

I use GitHub for Windows and provided shell.

Although description is present on web site `.git\description` file has default contents and `\description` file is absent in `root` folder. Where is the description of the project is stored then if it is present on GitHub?

I changed `.git\description` but the changes are not visible to the git status.

How to change the project description without creating `\description` file in the `root` folder or creating links to its `.git\description` version?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only change the GitHub repository descriptions of projects which you *own*. Simple read/write access is not enough to change that. You basically need the same privileges as you need to access the administration section of a project.

Comment: no, I do not own the projects. then for some repos I'm granted with permissions to change description I presume. even if I put \description file that will not take effect?

Comment: The description file, as @manojlds explained, only affects the repository you change it in. It will not transfer to other repositories. – You should be able to (only) edit the GitHub descriptions for projects where you can see a “Settings” tab (which only the owner has). If that’s not the case, I’d say you have to contact GitHub support.

Answer (score 15):

The `.git\description` file is only used in the Git-Web program. Github doesn't even bother about it, and the description that you enter in your local git repo remains local to you and will never be transmitted to the remote repo.

To change project description on Github, look here: [How do you change a repository description on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757751/how-do-you-change-a-repository-description-on-github)

Comment: in my case Edit is present in some repos and not present on others. I have full RW access to all of them

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy - Make sure you *do* have proper access.

Comment: I do have RW access displayed in github for that repo but no Edit button to appear. Other repos with the same RW access display Edit button.

Answer (score 4):

The edit button should show up when you move your mouse over the area where the description would show up.

A comment from the link manojlds pasted:

> apparently the description only appears in the details of the project if the project is not empty !. I had to commit something before being able to change it

Comment: The edit button is displayed on some repos and is not displayed on anothers. Though I have RW access to all of them.

Comment: project is not empty and we all commit to it

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy ah okay, check poke's answer