# How to add/change a repository description for github via the command line

Tags: github

I learned how to add a repository via the command line with curl and how to add a description for a commit with git commit, but how to add a repository description via the command line?

Comment: Do you mean using `git`? I don’t think you can, that’s a GitHub-specific thing. If you mean using GitHub’s API, check https://developer.github.com/v3/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15406525/6309), a repo description as seen on the GitHub website is specific to GitHub only.

So `.git/description` would not work (only [`gitweb` is using it](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb#gitweb-descriptionorcodegitwebdescriptioncode))

Using the GitHub API would, but you need to [integrate the verb `PATH` with your curl command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16445481/6309) in order to [edit your repo](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#update-a-repository).

```bash
curl \
  -X PATCH \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
  --data '{"name":"repo", "description":"a new description"}' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO
```

Using GitHub CLI [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api):

```
gh api \
  --method PATCH \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO \
  -f name='Hello-World'
  -f description='This is your first repository'
```

Or [`gh repo edit`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_edit):

```
gh repo edit OWNER/REPO -d "new Description"
```

Comment: when directy applying Your proposal, I got the error "Validation failed",..."field":"name" "message":"name is too short (minimum is 1 character)" ..., so by modifying Your --data -parameter to: '{"name":"repo", "description":"a new description"}', it worked!

Comment: @GeraldSchade Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: What does `:owner/:repo` mean? Is it a placeholder to be changed by e.g. vonc/repo1 ?

Comment: @Timo A placeholder indeed. You need to replace `:owner` with a GitHub user account, and `:repo` with one of their repositories.

Comment: Is ist still `patch` or is it now in v3 `post` as `request`?

Comment: @Timo Still PATCH. I have updated the documentation link and example, as well as added the GitHub CLI `gh` commands.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your are in your project's root, where you can locate `.git` directory, you should do the following steps:

Modify the description file:

```
vi .git/description
```

Delete the existing text (press `I` to switch to edit/insert mode ):

```
Unnamed repository; edit this file 'description' to name the repository.
```

Replace the default text with your project's description

```
My Awesome Project
```

To save the file and close vi editor. press `Esc -> X -> Enter`

Comment: as VonC wrote, this really did not work (for me), even after "git add -u", "git commit" and "git push".