# How do I change an organization's repository description on GitHub?

Tags: github

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757751/how-do-you-change-a-repository-description-on-github) way for changing the description for a repository owned by an individual user.

However, I also control a GitHub organization account and when hovering over repositories that belong to the organization, there is no such button. How can I edit the description of such repos?

Comment: Same thing. you must own the repository or be in the owner team of your organization

Comment: I own a company repository and the button appears

Comment: @CharlesB I am in the owners of the organization.

Comment: @iberbeu care to post a screenshot of how it appears? in which URL are you viewing the repos list?

Comment: I cannot put it but the URL is like: `https://github.com/CompanyName/Project` and the place is just below the buttons 'Code', 'Network', 'Pull Requests',....