# How do you suggest an edit to a repo's description in Github

Tags: github

I want to suggest an edit to a repo's description in Github.

For example, say I want to add more emoji's to the NodeJS repo description. How do I? I've tried making a pull request to a repo, but so far it doesn't seem to have affected anything.

[image: Screenshot of the nodejs/node Github repo description.]

I don't see this question as a duplicate of [How do you change a repository description on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757751/how-do-you-change-a-repository-description-on-github) as that question only deals with how to change your *own* repo description.

Comment: You can't. Maybe open an issue and ask. Or just don't, it doesn't need more emoji.

Comment: Description is not part of a git repo so you can't PR on it. However you can open an Issue and tell the ones with the GitHub permission to edit it.

Comment: @jonsharpe, haha I have no intention of adding more emoji, I was just using it as an example. Thanks for both your comments. If one of you two answer's I'll mark it as the correct answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be **No, you can't**. This is because the *repo description* isn't a part of [git](https://git-scm.com/), it's a GitHub specific feature.