# How do you set a repository description on GitHub? (2020)

Tags: github, repository

GitHub's UI changed since [How do you change a repository description on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757751/how-do-you-change-a-repository-description-on-github) and the edit button is no longer there. Also, I couldn't find anything in the settings.

[image: Missing GitHub description]

How do you do change the repository description since 2020? The cog can't be clicked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change a repository description on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757751/how-do-you-change-a-repository-description-on-github) Apologies for the automatic message, I would suggest migrating the answer there to avoid fragmenting the information, the original qualifies to be a canonical source, so an answer there could be much more beneficial

Comment: to SOCVR: added a community wiki to the original Q&A to be fair to the answer here and to be consistent with the close vote as duplicate. To everyone: feel free to update / rewrite / change / leave as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cog should be clickable. It opens a modal which allows you to change the repository description.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Didn't work until I updated and restarted Chrome :-) Wouldn't have expected that. Thank you.