# Make GitHub extract repo settings from a file

Tags: github, github-api

Is there a way to set repo settings inside a file so that GitHub displays them on the main page?

| Input (e.g. `.github.yaml` in `main` branch) | Output (repo [main page](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk)) |
| --- | --- |
| `meta_data: description: JDK main-line development website: https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk topics: [ java, jvm, openjdk ]` | [image] |

I'm looking for an answer without calling GitHub APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for an answer without calling GitHub APIs.

And yet, a call to [updating a repository API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-a-repository) would certainly be involved, through a [GitHub Action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions).

You can setup such an action triggered only by your file, in the `main` branch:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']
    paths: ['.github.yaml']
```

And use directly a [`gh repo edit -d '...'` call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70455907/6309), since the [GitHub CLI I is preinstalled on all GitHub-hosted runners.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows)

That way, each time you modify the `.github.yaml` file, you can regenerate the About message on your repository.

Comment: That will do. I just thought they have a standard basic functions covered. For example, like pypi.org which takes metadata of projects from setup.py file. But this answer opens eyes on other possibilities. Thanks, @VonC!